# the difference between these two logarithm

Tags: logarithms

I was just wondering what is the difference between ${1\over \ln(n^2)}$ and ${1\over \ln^2(n)}$

I know that ${1\over \ln(n^2)}$ is ${1\over 2\ln(n)}$ through the power rule, but I am not so sure about ${1\over \ln^2(n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Not a good example:** 
$$
  n = \mathrm e^2 \implies \frac{1}{\log n^2} = \frac14\qquad \frac1{\log^2n} = \frac14
$$
**Good example:** 
$$
  n = \mathrm e^3 \implies \frac{1}{\log n^2} = \frac16\qquad \frac1{\log^2n} = \frac19
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$\ln^2(n)=\ln(n)\cdot\ln(n)$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{1}{\ln^2(n)}=\frac{1}{\ln(n)\cdot\ln(n)}$$

Whereas:

$$\frac{1}{2\ln(n)}=\frac{1}{\ln(n)+\ln(n)}$$

---

They are equal if and only if $\ln(n)=2$, or in other words, if and only if $n=e^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $x = \frac{1}{\ln n}$, then
$$\frac{1}{\ln n^2} = \frac{1}{2\ln n} = \frac{x}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{\ln^2 n} = (\frac{1}{\ln n})^2 = x^2$$

You can clearly notice the difference between $\frac{x}{2}$ and $x^2$. Hope it cleared your doubt.